# Angularjs : How to always show modal login dialog if any REST API fails due to authentication

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog

My angular JS application is for an e-commerce usecase. There would be several pages, where some data would be fetched from some REST APIs which would be authenticated (and some not requiring authentication). If authentication fails (user not logged in), the APIs would all respond with a special error_code (say 'AUTH_FAIL').

My requirement is if any API fails due to authentication, then a login modal form dialog should appear in that page. This modal form contains the Username and password field. If the login succeeds, the modal window should close, and the current route should be re-freshed.

I understand how to do this for a particular route/controller. However, since there would be a lot of such pages where this would be needed, I'm unable to think of a way in which same piece of code could be easily utilized, since in my opinion, this does seem like a common requirement. How can it be done, or if not, what's the best way around it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use interceptors for this purpose. Inteceptors can be used for global error handling, authentication, or any kind of synchronous or asynchronous pre-processing of request or postprocessing of responses.

For example I use the following code to redirect user to login when authentication fails.

```
.factory('myInterceptor', ['$q', '$location', '$injector', function ($q, $location, $injector) {
    return {
        response: function (response) {
            return response || $q.when(response);
        },
        responseError: function (rejection) {
            if (rejection.status === 401) {
                var stateService = $injector.get('$state');
                stateService.go('login');
            }
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    }
}])
.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myInterceptor');
}]);
```

Comment: But how is it maintained that after login, the previous route is refreshed? I think this solution works if taking to a new /login route is acceptable. But suppose a page had an address form which user diligently filled, and then clicked on submit button, only to find that since it had not logged in, it now takes user to /login page. Now, I'd ideally want the data filled in previous route to be ready, and control to at least return there if login succeeds. Possible?

Comment: you can store previous state in $rootScope and redirect users to that state when they login

Comment: So, the data that they had filled also goes into the root Scope. This is not really working out well, since it there are dozens of views/routes where login is needed, I'll now need to maintain this history somewhere. With modal login dialog, it solves this problem easily, since the login dialog closes, and we come back to that view. Possible to do something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Using interceptors sounds like the most obvious and elegant solution, however I was never satisfied with it, mostly because of running into the circular dependency problems.

---

Here are some bits and pieces of logic from one of my apps using angular 1.6 and ui-router.

Some explanation about the business logic before you deep dive into the code.

I use JWT authentication and my server expects JWT to be passed as a header, hence the specifics of the `authService` implementation. The `authService` checks if the header is expired, and tries to send a JWT refresh request before actually showing a login dialog. Feel free to adjust it to your security implementation (e.g. session cookie/based or some other storage).

#### authService.js

This service is responsible for storing security token in the client. It returns a promise, which is resolved with the JWT token (if present or if it was refreshed). The promise is rejected when the token is expired and the service failed to obtain new token from the server.

```js
app.factory('authService', function($http, $q, $window, jwtHelper, API_HOST) {
  var storage = $window.localStorage;
  var cacheToken = {};
  var targetUrl = null;

  function saveToken(data) {
    var tokenPayload = jwtHelper.decodeToken(data.auth_token);

    storage.setItem('auth_token', data.auth_token);
    storage.setItem('refresh_token', data.refresh_token);
    storage.setItem('exp', tokenPayload.exp);
    storage.setItem('user_identifier', tokenPayload.user_identifier);

    cacheToken.auth_token = storage.getItem('auth_token');
    cacheToken.refresh_token = storage.getItem('refresh_token');
    cacheToken.exp = storage.getItem('exp');
    cacheToken.user_identifier = storage.getItem('user_identifier');
  }

  function setCacheToken() {
    cacheToken.auth_token = storage.getItem('auth_token');
    cacheToken.refresh_token = storage.getItem('refresh_token');
    cacheToken.exp = storage.getItem('exp');
    cacheToken.user_identifier = storage.getItem('user_identifier');
  }

  function isAuthenticated() {
    return cacheToken.auth_token && cacheToken.exp > moment(new Date().getTime()).unix()
  }

  setCacheToken();

  return {
    saveToken: function(data) {
      saveToken(data);

      return cacheToken;
    },
    getToken: function() {
      return cacheToken;
    },
    isAuthenticated: isAuthenticated,
    targetUrl: targetUrl,
    getAuthorizationHeader: function() {
      if (isAuthenticated()) {
        return $q.when({
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + cacheToken.auth_token
        });
      } else {
        cacheToken.auth_token = storage.getItem('auth_token');
        cacheToken.refresh_token = storage.getItem('refresh_token');
        cacheToken.exp = storage.getItem('exp');

        if (isAuthenticated()) {
          return $q.when({
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + cacheToken.auth_token
          });
        } else {
          if (!cacheToken.refresh_token) return $q.reject(null);

          return $http.post(API_HOST + '/tokens/refresh', {
            'refresh_token': cacheToken.refresh_token
          }).then(function(response) {
            saveToken(response.data);

            return {
              'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + cacheToken.auth_token
            };
          }).catch(function() {
            cacheToken = {};
            $window.localStorage.clear();
            return $q.reject(null);
          })
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

#### app.run block

This piece of logic is responsible for memorising the target url in case user tried to access protected resource, or when user token/session is expired. Please 2 things here: `authService.targetUrl` stores the URL and `authenticate` property on the ui-router state is used to check if the state is protected (e.g. if the authentication logic should be applied).

```js
$transitions.onBefore({
  to: function(state) {
    return state.self.authenticate;
  }
}, function(trans) {
  return authService.getAuthorizationHeader().then(function() {
    return null;
  }).catch(function() {
    authService.targetUrl = $window.location.href;
    $('#login-modal').modal();
    return trans.router.stateService.target('homepage');
  });
});
```

#### login modal directive

This piece of code stores the user token after login and also checks if the `targetUrl` is present in the `authService`, e.g. if a user tried to access protected resource some time before.

```js
scope.loginCallback = function(response) {
  authService.saveToken(response.data);
  jasprApi.User.me().then(function(response) {
    $rootScope.user = response.data;
    $(element).modal('hide');
    if (authService.targetUrl) {
      $window.location.href = authService.targetUrl;
      authService.targetUrl = null;
    }
  });
};
```

#### routes.js

Here is the ui-router states config which specified if the state should be protected

```js
.state('admin', {
  url: '/admin',
  //other configuration
  //...
  //...
  authenticate: true
})
```

#### api.js

A bonus — this is the sample from the file with the methods for accessing the API. Please note how `authService` is used here.

```js
updatePageAction: function() {
  return authService.getAuthorizationHeader().then(function(authHeader) {
    return $http({
      method: 'PUT',
      url: '/admin/page/update',
      headers: authHeader
    });
  });
},
```

---

I hope it helps!
Cheers